# App Engine Python module Basic and Manual scaling not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My Google App Engine application needs to run a lengthy calculation.  Automatic scaling on my module returns `DeadlineExceededError`, so I tried switching to manual and basic scaling.

For basic scaling, I added this to my yaml file.

```
instance_class: B2
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 5
  idle_timeout: 10m
```

But when I send a URL request to the module, my logs get flooded with 56:

```
/_ah/start 404
No handlers matched this URL.
```

Then eventually returns:

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

For manual scaling, I added this to my yaml file:

```
instance_class: B2
manual_scaling:
    instances: 1
```

But when I send a URL request to the module, after a while I get:

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

But nothing in the logs.

What am I missing?  Do I need to put a handler for `/_ah/start`?  I thought a 404 was acceptable to start the module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out.  I had to add a handler to my module.

I added:

```
- url: /_ah/start
  script: colors.handler.app
```

to my `handlers:` and it worked.

Comment: Maybe clarify that you need to add an empty handler just to return the 200 code?

Comment: @MichaelJohnston could  you please explain a bit what should be inside of the colors.handler.app file?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I just ran into this issue as well.

When an instance responds to the /_ah/start request with an HTTP status code of 200–299 or 404, it is considered to have successfully started and can handle additional requests. Otherwise, App Engine terminates the instance. Manual scaling instances are restarted immediately, while basic scaling instances are restarted only when needed for serving traffic.